# Oracle/Smarteam - How do I interpret a Date/Time value held as a number value

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

This is my first question on this so please feel free to correct me if I haven't put it in the correct format etc.

I have been asked to extract some metrics from our engineering product management system Smarteam. As a little bit of background Smarteam is a PDM product made by Dassault that stores engineering data in a back end database which in our case is Oracle 11g.

The metrics I'm trying to gather are time related metrics to do with the length of time each person takes as a drawing passes through a flow (release) process.

This is for the most part straight forward SQL queries. E.g.:

```
select OBJECT_ID, TDM_NAME, CREATION_DATE, TDM_END_TIME
from tdm_sf_process
where tdm_name = 'XXXX'
```

This gets me the start and end times for a flow process.

I am however having a problem interpreting a time value held in one of the tables.  The table `TDM_SF_PRC_HISTORY` contains a column called `TDM_ACTUAL_TIME` with a data type `NUMBER`.  The numbers held in this column take the format `0.000240601853874978`.

Can someone please tell me how one would go about converting this value to a useful date/time. It is probably something quite straightforward but it is not something I've come across before in my limited Oracle db experience.

Many Thanks

Comment: What is that column and how is it inserted? Is it the difference between `end_time` and `start_time`? The difference between two dates is a NUMBER. By the way, if it is a **DATE** then why is it stored as **NUMBER**? And if it is the difference of two dates, it shouldn't be stored at all. There is no point in storing computed values, unless it is something related to reporting.

Comment: Looks like the question actually is *How does the ENOVIA SmarTeam internal engine store dates?*

Comment: The TDM_SF_PRC_HISTORY column is of type 'NUMBER', it's values are inserted by the smarteam software during a flow process.  I've probably confused matters slightly with the example SQL i've used as it refers to another table.  The table i'm interested in has three date fields, a CREATION_DATE (the date a node was created), a MODIFICATION_DATE (all set to null) and TDM_RECEIVE_TIME (the date a node received its task).  There is no END_TIME or equivalent in this table.  This is why I suspect the TDM_ACTUAL_TIME column is a value representing the time from receipt until it is passed on.

Comment: Do you have any idea what this value (0.000240601853874978) really means in terms of hours:minutes:seconds? I can take innumerable guesses as to how the value of 0.000240601853874978 could be interpreted, but without knowing what the number really translates to it's all just guessing and hand-waving. Ultimately you might have to refer to Dassault's documentation to get an answer. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Bob, looking at the TDM_RECEIVE_TIME for the value I quoted  (0.000240601853874978) it is 02-OCT-2014 08:07:06 and the next node it passes to has a receive time 02-OCT-2014 08:07:09 (only 3 seconds difference) and a TDM_ACTUAL_TIME of 0.0000694444461259991.  It makes no sense to me and I have raised a call with dassault for assistance but I just wanted to put the question out there in case I was missing something very obvious. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness dassault responded to my query with an answer and it turns out I was being a bit stupid. Dassaults response was

> As I could see, the table TDM_SF_PRC_HISTORY contains the attribute TDM_RECEIVE_TIME, which contains the date and time of the income of the request, as described by you.
>   The attribute CREATION_DATE contains the information, when the request/Node 
>   has been accepted by the user and sent to the next Node.

So when I look at the table the CREATION_DATE field contains the date/time when the node passed the request on to the next person in the flow process.  This naming convention to me seems a little counter intuitive as I would have thought END_TIME/ACCEPT_TIME/END_NODE_TIME would have been more appropriate but there is probably a good reason for it.  Either way I still don't know what TDM_ACTUAL_TIME represents, it may be some form of internal processing time(?).

Thank you for your help.